# How to make the cancel Button work in Google App Script Browser Input Box

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison-operators

```
function sendEmails() {
  const sheet = getSpreadsheetApp()
  const sheetData = getSpreadsheetData(sheet).getValues();
  const subjectline = "Weekly Breakdown for the week of - "
  var subjectDate = Browser.inputBox('Please enter the date range for e-mail subject.', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if(Browser.Buttons.CANCEL = true) {
        Browser.msgBox('The operation has been cancelled')
        return;
      }

  const subject = subjectline + subjectDate
```

In the below code, even if I'm clicking OK by inputting the details to the input box,It gives me the same message box and stops running the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Browser.inputBox](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#inputBox(String,ButtonSet)) returns a text string. To find whether the **Cancel** button was pressed, use this:

```
    if (subjectDate === 'cancel') {
```

Use [Ui.prompt()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompttitle,-prompt,-buttons) to better detect what response was entered and which button was pressed.

Comment: I tried, not working again @doubleunary

Comment: Tried what? Please show your work by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74552543/edit) the question.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if(Browser.Buttons.CANCEL = true) {
    Browser.msgBox('The operation has been cancelled')
    return;
  }
```

should be:

```
if(Browser.Buttons.CANCEL == true) {
    Browser.msgBox('The operation has been cancelled')
    return;
  }

= is an assignment

== is a comparison
```

and  try this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Your Sheet Name")
  const sheetData = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const subjectline = "Weekly Breakdown for the week of - "
  var subjectDate = Browser.inputBox('Please enter the date range for e-mail subject.', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
    if(Browser.Buttons.CANCEL == true) {
        Browser.msgBox('The operation has been cancelled')
        return;
      }

  const subject = subjectline + subjectDate
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, the message box works. But still sends e-mail with a subject "Cancel" when I'm cancelling it from the input box

Comment: There is no `CANCEL` property in `Browser.Buttons`.